# Credential Manager DLL is causing login to hang when forcing a password change

Tags: windows, winapi, credential-providers

I've created a `Credential Manager` DLL to take advantage of the `NPLogonNotify` event. I'm testing this on a fully patched instance of `Windows 7 Ultimate`.

When the user logs in my implementation of `NPLogonNotify` spawns a couple processes using `CreateProcess`. These processes are Windows applications and everything works perfectly fine.

When I force the user to change their password on next login, they change their password and the system hangs on "Changing password". Something about creating a new process inside `NPLoponNotify` is not playing nice when a user changes their password.

I've verified that it is the `NPLogonNotify` code by commenting out ALL code in that export and testing the force password change. If I have all the code commented out, the password change works perfectly, with the code it hangs indefinitely.

**Below are the exported functions for the credential manager**

**NPGetCaps**

```
DWORD APIENTRY NPGetCaps(DWORD nIndex)
{
    DWORD ret = 0;
    switch (nIndex)
    {
    case WNNC_NET_TYPE:
        ret = WNNC_CRED_MANAGER; // credential manager 
        break;

    case WNNC_SPEC_VERSION:
        // We are using version 5.1 of the spec. 
        ret = WNNC_SPEC_VERSION51;
        break;

    case WNNC_DRIVER_VERSION:
        ret = 1; // This driver is version 1. 
        break;

    case WNNC_START:
        ret = 1; // We are already "started" 
        break;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

**NPPasswordChangeNotify**

```
DWORD APIENTRY NPPasswordChangeNotify(LPCWSTR lpAuthentInfoType, LPVOID lpAuthentInfo, LPCWSTR lpPreviousAuthentInfoType, LPVOID lpPreviousAuthentInfo, LPWSTR lpStationName, LPVOID StationHandle, DWORD dwChangeInfo)
{
    return WN_SUCCESS;
}
```

NOTE: the above function has no affect on the system hanging, I've tried leaving out the export altogether and I still get the same result.

**NPLogonNotify**

```
DWORD APIENTRY NPLogonNotify(PLUID lpLogon, LPCWSTR lpAuthentInfoType, LPVOID lpAuthentInfo, LPCWSTR lpPreviousAuthentInfoType, LPVOID lpPreviousAuthentInfo, LPWSTR lpStationName, LPVOID StationHandle, LPWSTR *lpLogonScript)
{
    lpLogonScript = nullptr;

    //auth type can help here to know what we're doing
    if (lstrcmpi(lpAuthentInfoType, L"MSV1_0:Interactive") != 0 && lstrcmpiW(lpAuthentInfoType, L"Kerberos:Interactive"))
        return WN_SUCCESS;

    WCHAR filename[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(g_Module, filename, MAX_PATH);
    wcsrchr(filename, L'\\')[0] = L'\0';

    WCHAR exe1Filename[MAX_PATH];
    wsprintf(exe1Filename, L"%lS\\exe1.exe", filename);

    STARTUPINFOW si = { 0 };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

    if (CreateProcess((LPWSTR)exe1Filename, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, 0, nullptr, nullptr, &si, &pi))
    {
        WaitForInputIdle(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    }

    MSV1_0_INTERACTIVE_LOGON *authInfo = (MSV1_0_INTERACTIVE_LOGON *)lpAuthentInfo;

    si = { 0 };
    pi = { 0 };
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);    

    ((PWSTR)(&((char *)authInfo->UserName.Buffer)[authInfo->UserName.Length]))[0] = L'\0';

    WCHAR args[(UNLEN + 14) * 2];
    wsprintf(args, L"exe2.exe %lS", authInfo->UserName.Buffer);

    WCHAR exe2Path[MAX_PATH];
    wsprintf(exe2Path, L"%lS\\exe2.exe", filename);

    if (CreateProcess((LPWSTR)exe2Path, (LPWSTR)args, nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, 0, nullptr, nullptr, &si, &pi))
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    }

    return WN_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm aware that the above code is pretty bad and has no error checking and is not secure. I'm doing this as a test and a learning exercise to learn more about Credential Managers.

Does anyone know why the code inside `NPLogonNotify` would work perfectly on user login but hangs the system completely when the user is forced to change their password on login?

Comment: hung in `WaitForInputIdle` or in `WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);` I be commented only this and test. if hang really here (no hung when you not wait) - task in your separate processes. I be launch debugger before (on current winlogon desktop) and view under it

Comment: @RbMm Good point, I'll take those out and see. I was assuming that it wasn't even getting to that point since nothing was displaying on the screen but it could be displaying but being something else or not being shown normally which would cause it to appear frozen. I'll update the question with the results

Comment: Have you tried... debugging?

Comment: @conio It's not easy to debug a DLL that is loaded before the system is even running. I'm assuming I would need to do remote debugging with a VM and potentially do kernel debugging but I haven't found any documents outlining how to properly debug a network provider/credential manager. If you know how, please let me know.

Comment: @conio yes I have tried google and I couldn't find what I was looking for, perhaps because I didn't know what to look for to begin with. Where is all your hostility coming from? This site is to help people, not berate them for not knowing the appropriate terms to use in searching google. Also, WinLogon doesn't handle loading network providers/credential managers, it's `mpnotify.exe`.

Comment: @vane - `It's not easy to debug a DLL that is loaded before the system is even running` - solution - your dll must yourself exec debugger on `WinSta0\Winlogon` desktop - so all is possible

Comment: @RbMm I was able to finally get it to debug by using Visual Studio Remote Kernel Debugging but it was very difficult since the documentation was pretty vague. I ended up having to call `__debugbreak` and load the `lsass.exe` module before it would actually break and allow me to step through C code instead of just assembly. I figured out what the problem is and will write an answer to outline it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still unclear on why my program would not display on a user password change but I've managed to figure out how to fix it. I needed to figure out a way to determine the difference between a call to `NPLogonNotify` when logging in and a call to it when a password is changing.

The issue with hanging was because I was calling `WaitForSingleObject` to wait for my program to exit before continuing so the program was running, it was just hidden and not intractable for some reason during a password change.

There's no documentation that I could find that clearly outlines the difference between a call when changing a password and a call when logging in so I was able to check with the below code:

```
if (lpPreviousAuthentInfoType != NULL || lpPreviousAuthentInfo != NULL || lstrcmpi(lpStationName, L"Winsta0") != 0)
    return WN_SUCCESS;
```

This may be excessive and probably not the proper way but I couldn't find any documentation on it. Basically, on a password change the `lpPreviousAuthentInfoType` will be populated with a string (different depending on type of authentication) and an empty string if a performing a normal login. `lpPreviousAuthentInfo` will contain a pointer to the previous user's credentials and NULL if a normal login. Finally, `lpStationName` will be `Winsta0` on a normal login and `SvcCtl` (if I remember correctly, I didn't write it down) on a password change.